# Find matching items in array of object values from array of filter criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have some data (json) that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Enterprise Networking",
        "technology": "Networking"
    },
    {
        "name": "Enterprise Networking",
        "technology": "Networking"
    },
    {
        "name": "Wireless Insights",
        "technology": "Mobility and Wireless"
    },
    {
        "name": "Mobility Insights",
        "technology": "Mobility and Wireless"
    },
    {
        "name": "Lock it down",
        "technology": "Security"
    },
    {
        "name": "Collaboration",
        "technology": "Security"
    }

]
```

I am trying to find matches based on an array of filtering options for one field named 'technology' in this example.   For example, my filtering criteria will be ["Networking", "Security"].  I would expect to return all objects that have 'Networking' and 'Security' as their technology, excluding 'Mobility and Wireless' in this example.

I have figured out how to do it with just one filter criteria using:

```
result = learningMapsDataObj.filter(el => el.Technology === filter3[0].value);
```

I've tried adding a method that will loop through the the filter array, but can't get it to work.

```
result = learningMapsDataObj.filter(el => el.Technology === myloopingArrCheckFunction(el.technology, filters3));
```

I know I'm close, but haven't had to dev in a while and my multidimensional brain isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Approaches

You can check if `el.technology` is [included](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in your array of values to filter by:

```js
const allowedTechnologies = ["Networking", "Security"];
learningMapsDataObj.filter(el => allowedTechnologies.includes(el.technology))
```

Alternatively, you can also check if `el.technology` is like [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) of the values to filter by:

```js
const allowedTechnologies = ["Networking", "Security"];
learningMapsDataObj.filter(el => { // Linebreak (thus function body) for readability
  return allowedTechnologies.some(allowedTech => allowedTech === el.technology);
})
```

## Map to string array

It seems your filter is in a form similar to this:

```js
const filter = [
  { value: "Networking" }.
  { value: "Security" }
];
```

But it would be easier to use if it was in the form as shown in my examples above. You can achieve that by [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the filter elements to their values:

```js
const filter = [
  { value: "Networking" }.
  { value: "Security" }
];
const filterValues = filter.map(el => el.value);
// Now you can use filterValues like allowedTechnologies
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = learningMapsDataObj.filter(el => el.technology === "Networking" || el.technology === "Security" );
```

Comment: Filtering by "Networking" and "Security" was just one example case. It should presumably be able to filter dynamically, which your code doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array with an array of criterias like this

```
const filterCriteria= ["Networking", "Security"]
const filteredArray = learningMapsDataObj.filter((item) => filterCriteria.includes(item.technology));
```

if you want to set a variable for fields you want to filter, you can also do something like this

```
const filterField = 'technology'
const filterCriteria= ["Networking", "Security"]
const filteredArray = learningMapsDataObj.filter((item) => filterCriteria.includes(item[filterField]));
```